# sql query for vertical data to horizontal data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How select the

```
000001  09/02/2013 7:58 In 
000002  09/02/2013 7:55 In 
000003  09/02/2013 7:48 In 
000004  09/02/2013 8:00 In 
000005  09/02/2013 8:00 In 
000006  09/02/2013 8:00 In 
000007  09/02/2013 8:05 In 
000008  09/02/2013 8:06 In 
000009  09/02/2013 8:06 In 
000010  09/02/2013 8:07 In 
000001  09/03/2013 01:00    Out 
000002  09/02/2013 16:00    Out 
000003  09/02/2013 16:01    Out 
000004  09/02/2013 16:02    Out 
000005  09/02/2013 16:03    Out 
000006  09/02/2013 16:04    Out 
000007  09/02/2013 16:30    Out 
000008  09/02/2013 16:05    Out 
000009  09/02/2013 16:10    Out 
000010  09/02/2013 17:30    Out 
000001  09/03/2013 7:58 In 
000002  09/03/2013 7:55 In 
000003  09/03/2013 7:48 In 
000004  09/03/2013 8:00 In 
000005  09/03/2013 8:00 In 
000006  09/03/2013 8:00 In 
000007  09/03/2013 8:05 In 
000008  09/03/2013 8:06 In 
000009  09/03/2013 8:06 In 
000010  09/03/2013 8:07 In 
000001  09/03/2013 16:00    Out 
000002  09/03/2013 16:00    Out 
000003  09/03/2013 16:01    Out 
000004  09/03/2013 16:02    Out 
000005  09/03/2013 16:03    Out 
000006  09/03/2013 16:04    Out 
000007  09/03/2013 16:30    Out 
000008  09/03/2013 16:05    Out 
000009  09/03/2013 16:10    Out 
000010  09/03/2013 17:30    Out
```

Output will be like the

```
Employee No. | Login Date      | LogOut Date
000001       | 09/02/2013 7:58 | 09/03/2013 01:00
000003       | 09/02/2013 7:55 | 09/02/2013 16:00
```

Comment: Dave, I suggest some formatting - that's quite hard to read.

Comment: Please improve the formatting and say what you want to do - if you have said, it's very hard to make out what you want.  Try marking your table with `Code Sample` in the editor so that it will format correctly, and add blank lines after a carriage return.

Comment: Your sample data includes multiple in/out times, which one do you want to have in the final result?

Comment: @bluefeet my guess is that it'd be in order, as it looks like a time and attendance system. So multiple rows, login-logout, login-logout, login-logout etc

Comment: @rots you are probably right but the OP should include that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
create table #events (Employee varchar(20),EventTime datetime,EventType varchar(10));

insert #events select '000001','09/02/2013 7:58','In';
insert #events select '000002','09/02/2013 7:55','In'; 
insert #events select '000003','09/02/2013 7:48','In'; 
insert #events select '000001','09/03/2013 01:00','Out';
insert #events select '000002','09/02/2013 16:00','Out';
insert #events select '000003','09/02/2013 16:01','Out';
insert #events select '000001','09/03/2013 7:58','In'; 
insert #events select '000002','09/03/2013 7:55','In'; 
insert #events select '000003','09/03/2013 7:48','In'; 
insert #events select '000001','09/03/2013 16:00','Out';
insert #events select '000002','09/03/2013 16:00','Out';
insert #events select '000003','09/03/2013 16:01','Out';

select Employee,LoginTime=EventTime,LogoutTime
from #events ein
cross apply (select top(1) LogoutTime=EventTime from #events eout where eout.Employee=ein.Employee and eout.EventTime>ein.EventTime and eout.EventType='Out' order by eout.EventTime) eout
where ein.EventType='In';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result, but first I would provide a sequence or distinct value that you can use to pair the login and logout dates.  This can be done by adding a `row_number()` to your query, doing this will allow you to return multiple rows for each employee.

The code for the pivot will be similar to the following:

```
select employeeno, 
  loginDate = [In], 
  logoutDate = [Out]
from
(
  select employeeno,
    date,
    inout,
    row_number() over(partition by employeeno, inout
                      order by date) seq
  from yourtable 
) d
pivot
(
  max(date)
  for inout in ([In], [Out])
) piv
order by employeeno;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a51c8/6). This query will return a result similar to:

```
| EMPLOYEENO |           LOGINDATE |          LOGOUTDATE |
|          1 | 2013-09-02 07:58:00 | 2013-09-03 01:00:00 |
|          1 | 2013-09-03 07:58:00 | 2013-09-03 16:00:00 |
|          2 | 2013-09-02 07:55:00 | 2013-09-02 16:00:00 |
|          2 | 2013-09-03 07:55:00 | 2013-09-03 16:00:00 |
|          3 | 2013-09-02 07:48:00 | 2013-09-02 16:01:00 |
|          3 | 2013-09-03 07:48:00 | 2013-09-03 16:01:00 |
|          4 | 2013-09-02 08:00:00 | 2013-09-02 16:02:00 |
|          4 | 2013-09-03 08:00:00 | 2013-09-03 16:02:00 |
```